# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'toLowerCase': object is null or undefined

Tags: jquery

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'toLowerCase': object is null or undefined

```
//--Customer Reviews
//--Display when current locale is EN-US
var IsReviewable = $(".tab-content-doc:eq(2) span")[0].innerText || $(".tab-content-doc:eq(2) span")[0].textContent;
if (IsReviewable.toLowerCase() == "true" && currentLocale()=="en-us" ) {            
   $("ul.tabs li").eq(2).show();
   $("#BVRRSummaryContainer").show();            
}
```

I try to execute the code and this error is showing. It gives me three options: Break,Continue and Ignore. If i continue then it will not display Customer Reviews but if i ignore then it display Customer Review.I need to display Customer Review. How can i get that? Its running on Internet Explorer 9.
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Can you run `console.log(IsReviewable);` and tell us what it puts out?

Comment: Maybe you should check for null first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your condition to

```
if (IsReviewable &&  IsReviewable.toLowerCase() == "true" && currentLocale()=="en-us" )
```

This will make sure the value is not falsy and only then apply the `toLowerCase` method

Comment: The `&&` will stop evaluating the rest of the statement if the first value is `false`, thus preventing calling NULL.toLowerCase(), which generated the error.

Comment: how do I solve this: **tsc.js(55958, 21) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'toLowerCase': object is null or undefined** seems like that is beyond my control..